# Add class to first-child ul without jQuery

Tags: javascript

This line but in pure javascript:

```
$('.container ul:first-child').addClass('new');
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.container ul:first-child').classList.add('new')`

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".container ul:nth-child(1)");
```

Now for adding class:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".container ul:nth-child(1)").forEach(function(c){
   c.classList.add("my-class");
});
```

---

If i have used `document.querySelectorAll` is because it is possible that document contains more than one `.container` class, else you can use other version of `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector(".container ul:nth-child(1)").classList.add("my-class");
```

---

**and** if you want to use simple `for` instead of `forEach`:

```
var All = document.querySelectorAll(".container ul:nth-child(1)");
for(var c in All) if(All.hasOwnProperty(c)) All[c].classList.add("my-class");}
```

Comment: Any reason to use `nth-child(1)` over `:first-child`?

Comment: `nth-child(1)` is more flexible. you can use both :)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) will need a polyfill if IE support is required

Comment: you can use simple `for`. please look at my last part of code.

Comment: All good, I was just predicting the next question from OP being _"It says `forEach` is not a function"_ :D

Comment: Thanks @Phil. you are right. It's not bad to consider old version of browsers too :D

Answer (score -1):

Add an id attribute to your ul, then:

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList").firstChild;
list.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Comment: _"Add an id attribute to your ul"_ <- why? Also, there's no guarantee the first-child will be a `<ul>`